# Why is my program saying my variables are not defined?

Tags: python, variables, syntax-error

```
loyalty = input("Do you have a Loyalty Card?: ")
x = loyalty.upper

if x == ("NO"):
    full_name = input("What is your full name?: ")
    
    spizza = int(input("How many small pizzas have you ordered?: "))

    mpizza = int(input("How many medium pizzas have you ordered?"))

    lpizza = int(input("How many large pizzas have you ordered?"))

elif x == ("YES"):
    print("Okay then. This may be the wrong page!")

pizza_total = open("pizza.txt", "a")

pizza_total.write("Full Name:" (full_name)+(spizza)+(mpizza)+(lpizza))
pizza_total.close()
```

This is my code. When I tried to run the program it kept on saying "full_name" is not defined.

After hearing that response many times I decided to delete the variable "full_name" as the program it wasn't defined but when I went to run it again the response given to me was that the next variable "spizza" wasn't defined. I then tried debugging and that didn't really work so that's why I decided to bring it in to the community so they could help.

Comment: What happens to `full_name` when `x` is not equal to `"NO"`?

Comment: `.upper` is a method. Call it with parentheses: `loyalty.upper()`. Also, the combination of `open()`/`.write()`/`.close()` is often frowned upon; use a context manager instead: `with open(...) as pizza_total: pizza_total.write(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I can see at least 4 errors:

1. If `x != 'NO'` then the variables are never defined, then you cannot use them afterwards.
2. You have to add parenthesis to `x = loyalty.upper`, i.e., `x = loyalty.upper()`.
3. you need to add an extra `+` in `pizza_total.write("Full Name:" (full_name)+(spizza)+(mpizza)+(lpizza))`
4. in that same line you're trying to concatenate `str` to `int`.

---

Just by guessing, I'd say this is what you want:

```
loyalty = input("Do you have a Loyalty Card?: ")
x = loyalty.upper()

if x == ("NO"):
    full_name = input("What is your full name?: ")
    
    spizza = int(input("How many small pizzas have you ordered?: "))

    mpizza = int(input("How many medium pizzas have you ordered?"))

    lpizza = int(input("How many large pizzas have you ordered?"))

    pizza_total = open("pizza.txt", "a")

    pizza_total.write(f"Full Name:  ({full_name}) ({spizza}) ({mpizza}) ({lpizza})")
    pizza_total.close()

elif x == ("YES"):
    print("Okay then. This may be the wrong page!")
```

Comment: Thank you Pablo for the help but on line 15 is the f before "full_name" supposed to be there or was It a typo?

Comment: @EmmanuelYeboah it's supposed to be there :) search for f-strings

Answer (score -1):

`full_name` is only defined inside a block that is reached only if `x == "NO"`, while your `pizza_total.write()` function is called in a global block. That means that if `x` is not equal to `"NO"`, `full_name` will never be declared but `pizza_total.write()` will try to use it nonetheless.

It is a good practice to always declare your variables that might be initialized in conditional blocks outside of them.

For example :

```py
def myfunc():
  my_var = ""
  if a == 2:
    my_var = "Yes"
  elif a == 3:
    my_var = 4
  print(my_var)
```

This way, even if no value is given to `my_var` in a block, I my script still works. That is part of exception management.